# What is the correct way to load a module from lib/?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Tournament model, which represents a tournament (I assume most people are familiar with what a tournament is). I want my tournaments to be accessed the same way, using RESTful routes, but I also wish to allow tournaments of multiple formats. Since there is a considerable amount of logic involved in generating a tournament in a particular format, I want a way to separate the format logic, and store that logic in a module. This is my setup:

In lib/formats/ I have single_elimination.rb:

```
module SingleElimination
  def test
    "Hello"
  end
end
```

I then modified my application configuration to add:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/formats/)
```

Finally, I added this to my Tournament model:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SingleElimination
  # ...
end
```

However, I get this error: `uninitialized constant Tournament::SingleElimination`

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you make sure to restart rails server when you added to config.autoload_paths ?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Thanks, that was the problem. I am so stupid :(

Comment: Remember you need to restart your app any time you change something outside of `app/` or `config/routes.rb`